# C#: Initial assignment of a property to a variable which holds a List<string> gets updated when later on RemoveAll is used on the same variable

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

We are performing a migration and we are supposed to log the final report for the same. To achieve the same, I have a class which has multiple properties that holds List of Ids(string) such as All the Ids involved in Migration, All the Ids which are Migrated etc.
While doing the same what I came across was that my previous assignment was getting updated when I performed a RemoveAll on a variable that holds all the List of Ids, to better understand, PFB an example:

```
public class Report {
  public IdsInfo AllIds {get; set;}
  public IdsInfo MigratedIds {get; set;}
  public IdsInfo FailedIds {get; set;}
}

public class IdsInfo {
  public int Count{get; set;}
  public List<string> Ids {get; set;}
  
  public IdsInfo(List<string> ids) {
    Count = ids.Count;
    Ids = ids;
  }
}

//An example of the Method that does the Migration
public Report Migrate(string criteria) {
  Report report = new Report();
  //Assume below is a DB Call
  List<string> allIds = db.getData(criteria).Select(x=>x.id).toList();//Assume Count = 1000
  report.AllIds = new IdsInfo(allIds);

  //Assume below is a DB Call to check whether Ids are already migrated
  List<string> migratedIds = db.getData(x=>allIds.contains(x)).Select(x=>x.id).toList();//Assume Count = 300
  allIds.RemoveAll(x=>migratedIds.contains(x));
  report.MigratedIds = new IdsInfo(migratedIds);
  return report;
}
```

What I was expecting =>

```
Report.AllIds.Count = 1000
Report.AllIds.Ids= {1000}//List
Report.MigratedIds.Count = 300
Report.AllIds.Ids= {300}//List
```

What actually happened =>

```
Report.AllIds.Count = 1000
Report.AllIds.Ids= {300}//List
Report.MigratedIds.Count = 300
Report.AllIds.Ids= {300}//List
```

I understand that Pass By Reference is what is causing this behavior but I would like to understand the reason behind this. My questions are as follows:

1. Since I am creating a new instance of the Class IdsInfo shouldn't it avoid Pass By Reference?
2. If Ans for 1 is no, then why is it that only the Ids List is updated and has 300 and the Count remains as is?
3. How to avoid this? I understand that I can use FindAll instead of RemoveAll and assign the values to a new variable, but what if I want to reuse the same variable as shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only because you create a new object of your type doesn´t mean you´re also creating a new *list*. In this line you just add a new **reference** to the same list.

```
report.AllIds = new IdsInfo(allIds);
```

So both `report.AllIds` and `allIds` will now reference the exact same list. Doing something on that list - e.g. by calling `RemoveAll`- is then reflected in all references to that list. You can read [more about reference-types in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types).

So what you need is to copy the list:

```
report.AllIds = new IdsInfo(allIds.ToList());
```

ALternativly you can also create the copy within the constructor of `IdsInfo`, as Guru mentioned in his answer.

`ToList` will *really* create a new list from the input-one, even if the input already is a list itself.

Answer (score 2):

`List<T>` is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types), so passing `allIds` into `IdsInfo` constructor will make `report.AllIds` and `allIds` point to the same one instance of the list, resulting in all modifying operations (like [`RemoveAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=net-5.0)) being observed in both places.

If you want to modify `allIds` later without affecting the instance inside the `report` just create a copy of the list with `ToList` (note that it shallow copies the contents of the list, which is fine for `string`'s but for other reference types can lead to similar behavior for elements of the list):

```
report.AllIds = new IdsInfo(allIds.ToList());
```